# Is there a way to sum pairwise in Octave, vectorized (ie. mapping and reducing matrices)?

Tags: matrix, octave, matrix-multiplication

Is there a way to sum pairwise in Octave?

If for example, I have a 10-row by 4 column. I want a new 10 row by 2 column, where each column is the sum of the pairs.

ex.

```matlab
[ 1 2 3 4
  2 3 4 5 
  ...
]           

=> [ 3 7 
     5 9
     ...
    ]
```

I know how to accomplish this using for loops and accumarray etc, but I'm just not sure if there's a way to do it that is completely vectorized.

Comment: If any of the answers below was useful to you, please [accept it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235). If not, leave a comment on those answers indicating why they don't, or edit your question to clarify.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are a few more options.

Given:

```
a = reshape(1:40, 10, 4)
a =

    1   11   21   31
    2   12   22   32
    3   13   23   33
    4   14   24   34
    5   15   25   35
    6   16   26   36
    7   17   27   37
    8   18   28   38
    9   19   29   39
   10   20   30   40
```

### Keep it simple

```matlab
b = [sum(a(:,1:2),2) sum(a(:,3:4),2)]
b =

   12   52
   14   54
   16   56
   18   58
   20   60
   22   62
   24   64
   26   66
   28   68
   30   70
```

---

### Squeeze a little

```matlab
b = squeeze(sum(reshape(a, [], 2, 2), 2))
b =

   12   52
   14   54
   16   56
   18   58
   20   60
   22   62
   24   64
   26   66
   28   68
   30   70
```

---

Or, my personal favorite...

### Mathemagic

```matlab
b = a * [1 1 0 0; 0 0 1 1].'
b =

   12   52
   14   54
   16   56
   18   58
   20   60
   22   62
   24   64
   26   66
   28   68
   30   70
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps someone comes with a better idea:

```
a = [1 2 3 4; 2 3 4 5]
b = reshape (sum (reshape (a.', 2, [])), [], rows(a)).'
```

gives

```
b =

   3   7
   5   9
```